# how to initiliaze unnamed semaphore with shared memory?

Tags: c, linux, fork, semaphore, shared-memory

I know that unnamed semaphores should be in shared memory area, but I don't know how to implement because mmap() returns a pointer to the mapped area, and i am obligated to use sem_t pointer, but this time, i think it s not really safe. Here what i did,

```
    sem_t *sem;
    char* name = "sharedSem";
    int fd;

    sem_init(sem, 1, 1);

    fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("fail");
        exit(-1);
    }
    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(sem_t));
    sem = (sem_t*) mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

When i use pointer, also i can't read the value of semaphore, i don't even know if it is possible..

Can i create an unnamed semaphore without sem_t pointer in shared memory area that children processes can also access?

Comment: I added right now, it is linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `sem_init` while `sem` is still not pointing anywhere in particular. Move that call to after you point it to the result of `mmap` (i.e., to the bottom of the snippet you posted).

Comment: and to use unnamed semaphore in another process(like children processes), do i have to open again or can i just use with the name of the semaphore in children processes?

Comment: @Wokers For child processes, you can just use the same `sem` variable in them too without any extra steps.